# how to play multiple video one by one in VideoView in android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

```
public class PlayMultipleVide extends Activity {

  VideoView videoView;
  @Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.multiplevideo);
    videoView=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    List<String> filedata=GetFiles("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2video/files");
    //specify the location of media file
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2video/files/"+filedata.get(0));
    //Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
  }

  public static ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {
    ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    File f = new File(DirectoryPath);
    f.mkdirs();
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    if (files.length == 0)
      return null;
    else {
      for (File file : files) MyFiles.add(file.getName());
    }
    return MyFiles;
  }
}
```

This is my code. I have one folder file. Inside that, there are 5 videos, which I want to play one by one in VideoView whenever launched. I dont know how to play video one by one in videoview one at  a time. Please suggest me .

Comment: You can get video length using `videoView.getDuration()` (probably in seconds) and then create timer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set [listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)) to your videoView:

```
void setOnCompletionListener (MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener l)
```

[*MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) will tell you when the video reached EOS (end of stream). And then restart playback with new video Uri. Continue to do that until you have uris in list (**List filedata**).

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/SFmY7t95VjB3F8kwjfKp4a  i tried like this but still not working please suggest me  what i am doing wrong @Sheikh

Comment: @Adevelopment, why do you not pass any new Uris to videoView ??? Try [https://paste.ofcode.org/35tneRQnhFWM7y9v4T46atN](https://paste.ofcode.org/35tneRQnhFWM7y9v4T46atN). Check it for errors and typos.

Comment: private void restartPlayback(Uri videoUri) {
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
  }
 this line Error coming at videoView.setVideoURI(uri);  @Sheikh

Comment: @Adevelopment, give more info. I edited your code in browser and there could be errors. What error?

Comment: @Adevelopment, by the way, you could need to add two calls `mediaPlayer.stop(); mediaPlayer.release();` in `onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)` method before restartPlayback.

Comment: which line can u please suggest

Comment: @Adevelopment, sorry those calls are not necessary. Please, check this code [https://paste.ofcode.org/75P8p6Y9Hue5kC8DCeuWTD](https://paste.ofcode.org/75P8p6Y9Hue5kC8DCeuWTD). I fixed some errors. Hope this will finally help you.

Comment: But where u have use relese and stop

Comment: I checked that stop and release are not necessary. I said it above.

Comment: @Sheikh thanks for sharing this valuable information.